# Expanding environment variables with double percent signs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, environment-variables

We received a VS2010 C# project that calls the function Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables();

I understand how to use this with a string such as "%variable%\something.exe", but the code we received uses this string - "%%variable%%\something.exe"

What is the purpose of having two percent signs surrounding the variable? is this a variable pointing to a variable? if so how can this work without calling ExpandEnvironmentVariables twice?

Comment: If you need to standardize it, why not string replace "%%" with "%"?

Comment: This is what I plan to do, they were calling Process.Start() on the result immediately after they expanded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%variable%%\something.exe` will expand to `%<value of variable>%\something.exe`.

You don't necessarily need a second call to ExpandEnvironmentVariables: the resulting string might get passed to an API that expands environment variables or it might get written to the registry as a REG_EXPAND_SZ or whatever.